# Better way to insert excel range as row and copy formats using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, com

I have to insert row of range which has many merged cells,styling and number format many times before writing data to them.
When I insert a row its not copying maerged cells ,style or number formats etc.
Hence I selecting range as a row and insert the same,and copying the previous row to newly inserted row.
This process taking more and more time as i had to do this many times .
This is how I'm doing

```
Range rangeToInsert = Worksheet1.get_Range("a" + Convert.ToString(20), "z" + Convert.ToString(20));
Range rangeToInsertRow= rangeToInsert.EntireRow;

rangeToInsertRow.Insert(app.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, false);
Range InsertedRowRange= Worksheet1.get_Range("a" + Convert.ToString(newrowNum), "z" + Convert.ToString(newrowNum));
rangeToInsert.copy(InsertedRowRange);
```

Please suggest if there is any optimization to my code to do Row insert/copying style faster.

Comment: Hi @Ram are you happy with the answer provided? Is there anything I can do to improve it so it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try like this

```
Range rngToCopy = ws.get_Range("A" + 20, "Z" + 20);
rngToCopy.Copy();
rngToCopy.Offset[1, 0].Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove);
```

also you could wrap the entire copy-paste snippet with (*before any work on cells*)

```
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

and (*after you've done modifying cells*)

```
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
```